# Grails/Compass - How can I change the compqass Connection to point to a different directory?

Tags: grails, runtime, compass-lucene

I use the Searchable plugin with Grails I have the need to change the directory to which Compass points to, depending upon a UI choice by the user.

Normally, this value is set in the compassConnection variable of the searchable map in grails-app/conf/Searchable.groovy, like so, and gets called at app startup time:

searchable { compassConnection = new File( "/path/to/index/file/directory" ).absolutePath

...

}

To do what I need to do, I think that I need to get a handle into the compass config variable and then call config.setConnection("/new/path/to/index/dir")

1. I don't know how I can get a reference to the config compass variable
2. Am I right in assuming that I need to call setConnection(String) only, or is(are) there any other step(s) I need to take?

Really appreciate any help that I can get,

Shailen

Answer (score 0):

In `Searchable.groovy` file, within `searchable { }` closure use this:

```
compassConnection = new File(
      "${userHome}/.grails/projects/${appName}/searchable-index/${grailsEnv}").absolutePath
```

Comment: Thanks Archer  for your response: my question has to do with changing the compassConnection _AFTER_ the setting in Searchable.groovy takes effect

Answer (score 0):

Well, sorry I was not careful reading your question. I guess this class must be your starting point: http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.2.0/api/